# Mysql best way to increase a column?

Tags: php, mysql

Given I know the value of `c`, what's better and why, please:

```
'UPDATE place SET c = c+1'
```

OR

```
'UPDATE place SET c = '.($c+1)
```

Comment: use `'UPDATE place SET c = c+1'` because it does not want to create a new variable where it is not required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **best** way is the one that won't get you fired....
Now, for a more serious answer, using SQL is, in most cases, preferable to sending data back and forth from client to server.

Answer (score 2):

The two queries do different things. The first updates c to c+1, so that rows where c is 2 get updated to 3, where c is 3 get updated to 4, and so on. The second query sets c to a fixed value, $c+1, which is the same for all rows.

"Which is better" is the wrong question. "What do I want to do" is the right one.

Answer (score 1):

I think the first is better, if you just want to increase the value of column `c`.
SQL is the origin way to manage database, and it will have a lot of advantages.